# monodroid compile error

Tags: xamarin.android

Late night fiddling with my mondroid app has thrown an error that has me sweating - I have a proof of concept demo to the stakeholders on monday morning so any help appreciated.

When I build the solution (VS2010 with monodroid eval) the following error appears in the output:

```
Error   1 Unable to copy file "C:\Projects\conxMono\conx.Monodroid\bin\Debug\conx.Monodroid.dll.mdb"    to "bin\Debug\bin\Debug\conx.Monodroid.dll.mdb". Could not find file 'C:\Projects\conxMono\conx.Monodroid\bin\Debug\conx.Monodroid.dll.mdb'.
```

From what I understand the mdb is a monodroid debug file?
Where has it gone, why has it gone and how do i create another? All the mdb files from the other projects in the solution are present in the debug dir.
Why is there a bin\debug\bin\debug directory on this solution and not on others?
I know I have probably done something arselike so will accept all derogatory comments that include a provided solution.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to clean the solution and rebuild.  If that doesn't work, go into the project settings of conx.Monodoroid, go to the Build tab and make sure the Output Path is set to bin\Debug\

It is possible that this file became read-only, so go to that directly, right click the folder and make sure read-only isn't checked.